# Add results of recursive promises to array

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, bluebird

I have a series of recursive promises which traverse up a hierarchy getting the parent of the current node until it reaches the top. I can get the results fine, but I don't know how to store the result. I am using Bluebird to create the getNodeData promise.

```
var getParent = function(node) {
    getNodeData(node)
        .then(function(node) {
            if (term.parent) {
                getParent(node.parent);
            } else {
                //return all the nodes as an array
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: If this is async code, you need to be returning promises to allow `.then()` to do its job and for you to be able to return the final data through the promises.  What does `dataRetriver.getNodeData()` return?

Comment: Always `return` promises from asynchronous functions!

Comment: @jfriend00 getNodeData just resolves with an object with the details of that leaf.

Comment: resolves with an object?  Does that mean it returns a promise?  Hiding the implementation details of `getNodeData()` is NOT helping anyone help you here.  If I knew what it did from the beginning, I would have posted an answer within an hour of your question, but as such, I still don't understand enough about it to post an answer that isn't a guess.  You have to help people help you and leaving out important implementation details doesn't help people understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your statements to return and add a second function to chain to do something with the responses from those promises.

```
var getParent = function(term, classifier) {
    return dataRetriver.getNodeData(node)
        .then(function(node) {
            if (term.parent) {
                return getParent(node.parent);
            } else {
                //return all the nodes as an array
                return node;
            }
        });
    };
};

getParent(term, classifier)
.then(function(node){
    // do stuff with the node
});
```

Comment: I'm returning these now, but in my getParent.then I only receive the top leaf of the tree - I need the whole line going up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the tree can be climbed in the absence of nodeData, you can split the process into two :

- traverse the tree to find the ancestor nodes
- scan the found ancestor nodes to gather the nodeData

And finally return an aggregate promise that will resolve when all nodeData has arrived.

The whole process is best wrapped in another function, something like this :

```
function getAncestorData(node) {
    function getParent(arr, node) {
        arr.push(node);
        if(node.parent) {
            return getParent(arr, node.parent);
        } else {
            return arr;
        }
    };
    var nodes = getParent([], node);
    var promises = nodes.map(function(node) {
        return dataRetriver.getNodeData(node);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

or, more concisely :

```
function getAncestorData(node) {
    function getParent(arr, node) {
        arr.push(node);
        return node.parent ? getParent(arr, node.parent) : arr;
    };
    return Promise.all(getParent([], node).map(function(node) {
        return dataRetriver.getNodeData(node);
    }));
}
```